# How to minimize the following polynomial over a four-dimensional sphere: $(c_0x_0^2+c_1x_1^2+c_2x_2^2+c_3x_3^2)^2+\sum_{nm}c_{nm} x_nx_m $

Tags: polynomials, optimization, groebner-basis

I need to find the global minimum of the following polynomial over a four-dimensional sphere.

$$f(x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3) = \left( \sum\limits_{j=0}^3 c_j x_j^2 \right)^2 + \sum\limits_{n,m=0}^3 c_{nm} x_n x_m $$

Here $x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3$ are the variables and are constrained to be on the four-dimensional sphere, i.e.,

$$\sum_{n=0}^3 x_n^2=1$$

and $c_j\ (j = 0, 1, 2, 3)$ and $c_{nm}\ (\{ n, m\} = 0,1,2,3)$ are problem constants that can be positive or negative or zero.

Well, I am aware of the general method; find the derivatives calculate the roots etc... however as you can see the problem has some sort of simple structure (quartic part can be diagonalized) so I am wondering if there is a simpler solution. It is also possible to diagonalize the quadratic part and leave the quartic part complicated.

Comment: Try Lagrange optimization (i.e., a mento for optimization given a constraint).  But your problem is unclear:  the unit sphere has just $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$.  What is $x_0$?  Can it actually be a variable?  What does it have to do with a sphere?

Comment: Does the range of summation include $0,1,2,3$?

Comment: Yes I have edited now. @David G. Stork Yes, thanks. Does the fact that the quartic part can be diagonalized leads to some simplification here?

Comment: Are the $c_0,...,c_3$ positive?

Comment: @copper.hat No actually, they can be negative.

Comment: I still don't understand the "unit sphere" part.  Is this a four-dimensional sphere?  Do we have $x_0^2+x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=1?$

Comment: Yes, I have edited now.